How to get a link with subdomain either using url() helper or route() helper in Laravel?
I have set up my subdomain domain routes like this:-
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.' . env('APP_URL'), 'prefix' => 'console', 'namespace' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'subdomain'], function () {
   Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index')->name('admin.login');
});

And main domain routes like this-
Route::group(['prefix' => 'console', 'namespace' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'maindomain'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index')->name('admin.login');
});

Now in an email, I want to send the login url of the subdomain.

If I simply write route('admin.login') it will give me the login
url of the main domain.
url() . 'console/login' will also give me
the login url of the main domain.

How can I get/print the login url of the subdomain?

url() or route() or secure_url() all create the full url based on the domain the request is coming from. For example if you hit your controller route from main domain your url will be made with main domain and if you hit your url from subdomain urls will be created with subdomain.
You will have to achieve this manually if both your domains are directing to same project folder.

To access subdomain-route use this
route('admin.login','subdomain') // `subdomain` that you defined in Route

Point to Note :-
As per official docs you need to register subdomain-routes before registering root domain-routes. This will prevent root domain routes from overwriting subdomain routes which have the same URI path.
Check the link below for detailed information--
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing
Try this ,It will resolve the issue.

You can prefix your Route groups with a name to make both login route names unique. Here’s how you can do it:
Define Route Groups

For Subdomain Routes:


Route::name('subdomain.')->group([
    'domain' => '{subdomain}.' . env('APP_URL'),
    'prefix' => 'console',
    'namespace' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'subdomain'
], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index')->name('admin.login');
});


For Main Domain Routes:


Route::name('domain.')->group([
    'prefix' => 'console',
    'namespace' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'maindomain'
], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index')->name('admin.login');
});

Resulting Route Names
With these definitions, your routes will be:

Subdomain Login Route:


route('subdomain.admin.login')


Main Domain Login Route:


route('domain.admin.login')

By naming the route groups, you ensure that both login routes have unique names, preventing any naming conflicts.

Same as route parameters.
route('admin.login', ['subdomain' => 'sub']);

url('console/login', ['subdomain' => 'sub']);

More importantly, never use env() outside of config files.
Route::domain('{subdomain}.'.config('app.url'))->group(function () {

});

The information you're using as reference is outdated.
